# seo friendly urls in YII framework with id and name

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, yii-components, yii-url-manager

I've been searching all around Stackoverflow and YII forums, there are many answers,
which didn't help me...

This is my case.

I have controller called: **proj** and an action called **view**.
It gets: **id**(int), **name**(string).

The desired name gets sometimes with special chars such as: [**+,!#$%^&*-**]

So when I'm running **createUrl()** function it returns me not so friendly url.

For example:
http://www.qa-mysite.com/proj/1029/Conservation+of+the+Vermont+Salt+Pan+System%2C+Hermanus%2C+South+Africa.

id = 1029
name = Conservation of the Vermont SaltPan System, Hermanus, South Africa.

I want the result to be:
http://www.qa-mysite.com/proj/1029/conservation-of-the-vermont-salt-pan-system-hermanus-south-Africa

So actually i need to strip the special chars and change the delimiter between spaces to "-" instead of "+".

My current configurations of the curlManager are:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'appendParams' => true,
            'rules'=>array(
            //array('proj/view/<name:\w+>', 'pattern'=>'proj/<id:\d+>'),
                //'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                'proj/<id:\d+>/<name:\w+>'=>array('proj/view', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
                '<controller>/<id:\d+>/<name:.*?>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        )
```

CreateUrl example:

```
$this->createUrl('proj/view', array('id' => $data->id, 'name' => $data->name));
```

After the urls will be changed I need to do **301 redirects** of the old ones to the new-seo-friendly urls.

Note: I cannot do hardcoded str_replace.

Many thanks for any help :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own url manager by subclassing `CUrlManager` and ovveride `createUrl` a bit, in example:

```php
class MyUrlManager extends CUrlManager {
    public function createUrl($route,$params=array(),$ampersand='&') {
        if($route == 'proj/view' && isset($params['name'])) {
            $params['name'] = processYourParamFunction($params['name']);
        }
        return parent::createUrl($route,$params,$ampersand);
    }
}
```

Then modify your config to use this class:

```
...
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'MyUrlManager'
...
]
```

It is one of great Yii features, natural [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control):)

**For second part of question:**

In you view action simply redirect to new url with createurl if you detect unwanted characters . Just make sure you not hit redirect loop.

**Update:**

To redirect with 301 just pass redirect code a third param to redirect call:

```
$this->redirect('route', true, 301);
```

**Side note:**

Use [cannonical](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394) to point search engines to proper url

Comment: TNX :] I want that the old urls will be accessible & when you'll enter them, the server will preform 301.

Answer (score 3):

First of all PeterM's answer is a good one, It's a nice approach.

I've did it in a different way.

I've created helper called "**TextHelper**", with one static function:

```
class TextHelper{
    public static function cleanText($text=""){
        $text = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9]+/i', '-', $text);
        $text = strtolower(trim($text, '-'));

        return $text;
    }
}
```

And changed the **createUrl()** to get cleaned by the **cleanText()**, like this:

```
$this->createUrl('proj/view', array('id' => $proj->id, 'name' => TextHelper::getSlug($proj->name)));
```

For last, my **config/main.php**:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'appendParams' => true,
            'rules'=>array(
                'proj/<id:\d+>/<name:\w+>'=>array('proj/view', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
                '<controller>/<id:\d+>/<name:.*?>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        )
```

That solution did the job for me.
Hope it will be easy and efficient solution for other developers which need to face this problem.

Comment: It's also possible to store these slugs in a DB and drop the ID all together (even nicer urls).

Answer (score 0):

That solution did the job for me. Hope it will be easy and efficient solution for other developers which need to face this problem.

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                'urlFormat'=>'path',
                'showScriptName'=>false,
                'appendParams' => true,
                'rules'=>array(
                    'proj/<id:\d+>/<name:\w+>'=>array('proj/view', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
                    '<controller>/<id:\d+>/<name:.*?>'=>'<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                ),
            )
```